# Make Excel Row Height Stay when Sorted

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, sorting, cells

I have an Excel 2007 spreadsheet and need to make some rows bigger than others so there is vertical space for a signature.

These cells are colored differently, but  the height doesn't stick with the cells when it's sorted with the rest of the doc. The text in these rows is short so doesn't need wrapping and auto-adjusting the cell height won't work.

Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Excel's "Auto Fit Row Height" feature actually auto fit the row height?](http://superuser.com/questions/389976/how-to-make-excels-auto-fit-row-height-feature-actually-auto-fit-the-row-heig)

Answer (score 0):

Add a column within the block to be sorted (can be hidden later) and apply wrapping to it. Insert enough text into a cell in that column and the desired row or rows such that the row/s open/s up as required.